# Question about an argument in Lang's Calculus of Several Variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation

[image: Screenshot from Lang's book]

Hello, I am having trouble understanding the above argument from Lang's *Calculus of Several Variables*, pp.64-65. I understand the author is not being completely rigorous in this book.

Nonetheless, when we replace $h$ by $-h$, shouldn't we replace $f(x+h)$ with $f(x-h)$. I'm just very unclear about what's going on here. If someone could give some color, I'd be more than happy.

Edit: I think that I should also add how the author continues - with the converse - assuming the existence of such a function $g(h)$ and proving differentiability. I think it clarifies.

[image: Second quote from the book]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g$ be as above for $h \neq 0$ and define $g(0) = 0$. Then $g$ is continuous at zero and $g(0) = 0$.

Now define $\tilde{g}(h) = \operatorname{sgn} (h) g(h)$, then $hg(h) = |h| \tilde{g}(h)$.

Since $f(x+h) = f(x) + f'(x)h + h g(h)$ we have
$f(x+h) = f(x) + f'(x)h + |h| \tilde{g}(h)$.

Note that it is the fact that $g(0) = 0$ that lets us do this and keep $\tilde 
g$ continuous.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. However, the author doesn't use $\tilde{g}(h)$, he just uses $g(h)$. 

Is he changing the definition of $g(h)$ without introducing new notation? I guess in the second instantiation of $g(h)$ above, $g(h)$ is supposed to be an existential variable (i.e. there exists a function $g$ such that) - not defined before.

This could have been written more clearly. Please confirm my explanation (will accept your answer once you do) and thanks again.

Comment: The author  is using $g$ for both of $g$ and $\tilde g$ above. It is a bit confusing. He just wants to conclude that a $g$ satisfying the last equation in the question exists.

Comment: Just to note, it is more usual in such things to use the first $g$ (that is, the remainder is $h g(h)$ than the second. But the author gets to choose :-).

Comment: Thank you so much. It does make a whole lot more sense - I feel so relieved. I'm glad I asked. Thank god for math.stackexchange .

Comment: I understand completely. I have a little experience but often read (sometimes elementary) texts and wonder what in God's name the author is doing. It is surprisingly difficult to communicate even simple ideas clearly & concisely.